# Is it possible to remove unwanted packages from docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to reduce the size of my docker image which is using Centos 7.2 
The issue is that it's 257MB which is too high... 
I have followed the best practices to write Dockerfile in order to reduce the size... 
Is there a way to modify the image after the build and rebuild that image to see the size reduced ?

Comment: Don't use `CentOS` use `alpine` instead. Start from something which is already small instead of trying to make something small

Comment: thanks for your answer but the package i need to install needs yum to be installed so alpine is not the solution for me ...

Comment: Then look at the answer I posted

Comment: I'm testing it :)

Comment: I have this error: Error response from daemon: minimal is not a valid change command

Comment: Chuck that `-c ....`, updated the answer. That is not needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all if you want to reduce an OS size, don't start with big one like CentOS, you can start with alpine which is small

Now if you are still keen on using CentOS, do the following:

```
docker run -d --name centos_minimal centos:7.2.1511 tail -f /dev/null
```

This will start a command in the background. You can then get into the container using

```
docker exec -it centos_minimal bash
```

Now start removing packages that you don't need using `yum remove` or `yum purge`. Once you are done you can commit the image

```
docker commit centos_minimal centos_minimal:7.2.1511_trial1
```

**Experimental Squash Image**

Another option is to use an experimental feature of the `build` command. In this you can have a dockerfile like below

```
FROM centos:7
RUN yum -y purge package1 package2 package2
```

Then build this file using

```
docker build --squash -t centos_minimal:squash .
```

For this you need to add `"experimental": true` to your `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and then restart the docker server

Comment: the second solution works but not the first one, thank you